# TB fluid div alignment issue from hyde generated code

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, jinja2, hyde

I have the following [responsive blog archives layout](http://jsfiddle.net/NpDXy/), which is suffering from alignment issues but I'm not sure which element to target to remedy the issue.

In the linked [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NpDXy/), adjusting the width does produce a responsive layout, but the listing of blog posts does not flow in proper alignment.

The below code from the hyde static site generator seems to put redundant `<p>` tags in, which I'm not sure if it needs to be remedied there or if some CSS adjustments will suffice.

```
{% extends "base.j2" %}
{% from "macros.j2" import render_excerpt with context  %}
{% block main %}
{% block page_title %}

<h1 class="title"></h1>

    <div class="page-header">
    <h1>{{ resource.meta.title }}</h1>
    </div>


{% endblock %}


  <div class="row-fluid">

    {% for res in resource.node.walk_resources_sorted_by_time() %}


    {% refer to res.url as post %}

        <div class="span4">
              <a href="{{ content_url(res.url) }}"><h2>{{ res.meta.title }}</h2></a>

    <a href="{{ content_url(res.url) }}" class="postpic">{{ post.image|markdown|typogrify }}</a>

{{ res.meta.excerpt|markdown|typogrify }}

              <p><a class="btn" href="{{ content_url(res.url) }}">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->

    {% endfor %}

          </div><!--/row-->


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Add a tag for the language that are you using for generate the page! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a grid is best that every 3 span4 you generate a new row-fluid below the other. For example:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12"> //These two row are our flexible container
     / GENERATE WITH YOUR CODE THIS STUCTURE UNDER EVERY 3 POST /
     <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="span4"></div>
       <div class="span4"></div>
       <div class="span4"></div>
     </div>
```

I use the php for doing it, but I think that is a small error of logical structuration of your html in the cycle!

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it out!